# Ionic 4 CDN & VueJS Button Styles not working

Tags: ionic-framework, vue.js, ionic4

Hello i am using the Ionic 4 CDN in my VueJS application.
However everything looks like it is working fine except the Buttons.

```
<button ion-button>Button</button
```

This is how i add the CDN (offical docs):

```
<script src='https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@0.0.2-20/dist/ionic.js'></script>
```

i am adding the button exactly how it is shown in the Offical Ionic 4 Docs but the Button is not styled.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use these links instead:

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.0-beta.7/css/ionic.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ionic/core@4.0.0-beta.7/dist/ionic.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should say explicitly to try a more recent version.

Comment: This is something I was missing. I was not having link to ionic.css causing all sort of issues. I no document I found that we have to link CSS. Thanks @jns